# Unable to perform a dask merge

Tags: python, merge, dask, space

I have a huge dataframe called Network consisting of two columns (integers): "NiuSup", "NiuCust" and 5 Million observations.
I am trying to perform a merge using dask as follows:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
NetworkDD = dd.from_pandas(Network, npartitions=Network['NiuSup'].nunique())
NodesSharingSupplier = dd.merge(NetworkDD, NetworkDD, on='NiuSup').query('NiuCust_x != NiuCust_y').compute()
```

however I incur in a "Not enough space left on device" Error. I have 80 GB in SSD left and I have noticed is that, at a certain point of the merge, the SSD drops until the merge is forced to stop and the error occurs. The the SSD goes back almost to its original value.
My suspect is that dask creates some huge temporary files (maybe log files?) that drop memory down and unable the merge when .compute() is typed. So two solutions I thought are:

1. Perform the merge and force dask to store everything online in dropbox repository (where I have 2 TB)
2. Force dask not to write anything on the local machine.

Now, since I am quite new to dask, I cannot perform either 1 nor 2 and I don't know even if they are possible solutions or desirable ones. Could you please help me out figuring a way to perform such a merge please?

Comment: Hi, how many unique 'NiuSup' value do you have? This might lead to a lot of partitions on 5 millions row. You could also try to use the Distributed Scheduler and follow your computation uising Dask Dashboard to see where the problem might come from.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB thanks for the reply. I have 412044 unique partitions. I have never used the Distributed Scheduler. Where can I find more info?

Comment: > 400000 partitions is quite a lot for Dask, what is the volume of your Data? In order to use Distributed and the Dashboard, you just have to start a Client, see: https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/quickstart.html